# how to make hint disappear when edittext is touched?

Tags: android, android-edittext, hint

In my application in android are many EditText fields. And I ran into a problem with hint.
It is not disappearing when EditText is focused, but it disappears when I start to write something.
How can this problem be fixed? Because I need the hint to disappear when the EditText field is touched.

It is for example:

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:id="@+id/driv_lic_num_reg"
    android:hint="@string/driver_license_numb"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textColorHint="@color/grey_hint"
    android:background="@drawable/input_field_background"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@color/black"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/pass_reg"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:maxLength="50"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
```

Comment: Can you post the XML of your Edittext?

Comment: It works that way. Hint disappears as soon as any text is entered.

Comment: For `TextInputLayout` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251342/textinputlayout-and-edittext-double-hint-issue to remove double hint.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Hint only disappears when you type in any text, not on focus. I don't think that there is any automatic way to do it, may be I am wrong. However, as a workaround I use the following code to remove hint on focus in EditText

```
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus)
            myEditText.setHint("");
        else
            myEditText.setHint("Your hint");
    }
});
```

Comment: @Tobor that can be easily managed using some logic. I just want to give solution to hide the hint on focus.

Comment: @user3132940 If my answer solved your problem then please accept it and mark the question solved.

Comment: @RohanKandwal You probably meant `setOnFocusChangeListener`, not  setOnFocusListener.

Answer (score 87):

You can also custom your XML code by using Selector. Here is an example code.

Create a selector. In file **selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
    <item android:color="@color/gray" />
</selector>
```

In your view

```
android:textColorHint="@drawable/selector"
```

Comment: This is the most elegant answer, no code involved, 100% XML. More reusable & maintainable. +1

Comment: Excellent answer, very concise and not code polluting.

Comment: or just set it to transparent color `"#00000000"`

Comment: The resource item should reside under `res/color` instead of `res/drawable`, shouldn't it?

Comment: Very perfect ! Thanks~~

Comment: For some reason app theme is overriding the state_focused in runtime

Comment: @AtikM. I had the same problem, I used app:hintTextColor="@color/selector" instead and then it worked

Answer (score 10):

Here's my solution, where the hint disappear when user focus editText and appears again when focus changes to other place if the edittext is still empty:

```
editText.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        editText.setHint("");
        return false;
    }
});

editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (!hasFocus) {
            editText.setHint("Hint");
        }
    }
});
```

hope this helps someone

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution:

```
final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.activity_edittext);
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            editText .setHint("my little hint");
        } else {
            editText .setHint("");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The proposed selector solution by windyzboy doesn't work for EditTexts with centered text, because the cursor stays behind the transparent hint text instead of moving to the center.

A good way without polluting your code is to make a custom EditText, since you probably need the same style in the whole application. That way you can avoid adding checks for each EditText separately.

```
public class HideHintEditText extends EditText {

    CharSequence hint;

    public HideHintEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
        hint = this.getHint();
    }

    public HideHintEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        hint = this.getHint();
    }

    public HideHintEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        hint = this.getHint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
        super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);

        this.setHint(focused ? "" : hint);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(...);
editText.setHint("");
```

in your `onTouch` logic. 
 However your hint must be dissapearing when you clicked on edit text.
 So **re-check** your app logic.

Comment: What do you meen "re-check your app logic"?
Because i'm actually don't understand why it is working like that

Answer (score 0):

Here i have used the little bit of code to hide and show hint
may be it'll be helpful.

```
txt_username.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(txt_username.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                    if(hasFocus){
                        txt_username.setHint("");
                    }else{
                        txt_username.setHint(R.string.username);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
findViewById(R.id.mainLayout).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hideKeyboard();
                editText.clearFocus();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString())) {
                    editText.setHint("your hint");
                }
            }
        });

        editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                editText.setHint("");
                return false;
            }
        });


        editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (hasFocus)
                    editText.setHint("");
                else
                    editText.setHint("your hint");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is like this. It shows hint when empty and not focused and hides if there is text or if it is touched

```
fun hideHint() {
        tilFloating.isHintAnimationEnabled = false
        etFloating.onFocusChangeListener = OnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
            if ((etFloating.text != null && etFloating.text.toString() != "") || hasFocus)
                tilFloating.hint = ""
            else
                tilFloating.hint = mHint
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I like to do it (now in Kotlin) is to have the hint reappear if the user clicks elsewhere. Initialize the hint-string outside of your class, also importing your synthetic layout there:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_layout.*
private const val MY_HINT= "The Hint Shown"
```

Then use an OnFocusChange listener:

```
    myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener() { v, event ->
        myEditText.hint = if(myEditText.hasFocus()) "" else MY_HINT
        false
    }
```

That way the hint doesn't get lost as the user clicks around. Or, just set it to an empty string if you don't care about that!

Answer (score -1):

Every Given Solution may work or not I don't know but the Following steps would definitely help.

First Create a dummy focus to restrain the EditText from gaining focus by

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="0px"/>
```

Then Normally set hint in your EditText as example:

```
    <EditText

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:hint="Your Hint"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
   />
```

Finally add the following code in your activity or fragment where you intend

```
    editText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            editText.setHint("");
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
android:hint="User Name"
```

This code line can be done that easily way!

```
<EditText
  android:id="@+id/edtUserName"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:ems="10"
  android:inputType="textPersonName"
  android:hint="User Name" />
```