# Need to make double hint in EditText with TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, textinputlayout

Here is the problem with double hint - [TextInputLayout and EditText double hint issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251342/textinputlayout-and-edittext-double-hint-issue)

I need to do the same. I need two hints. One is a title of EditText, and second is a possible value if nothing wasn't input.

But unfortunately there is only one tag:

```
android:hint
```

Can I do something with it?

**UPD1:**

The answer was to set hint for EditText programatically and hint for TextInputLayout in xml.

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:hint="@string/prompt_quantity"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/quantity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And

```
    quantityEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            quantityEditText.setHint(hasFocus ? "0" : "");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Use this LIB. https://github.com/activesince93/CustomViews

Comment: Can refer : "Adding helper text to a text field" in this link https://m2.material.io/components/text-fields/android#using-text-fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check your input and change the hint depending on that:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
{
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) 
    {
        if(editText.getText().toString().equals(""))
            editText.setHint("");
        else
            editText.setHint("Your normal hint");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

With the Material Components library you can use

- `android:hint="Label"` to add a floating label
- `app:placeholderText="Placeholder Text"` to add a placeholder in the `EditText`.

Use something like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:hint="Label"
    app:placeholderText="Placeholder Text"
    ..>

     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

**Note:** it requires at least the version `1.2.0-alpha03`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/non_active_edit_text"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:hint="Right"
            android:paddingTop="4dp"
            android:background="@null"/>


    <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/active_edit_text"
            android:hint="Left"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
</merge>
```

JAVA class

```
public class TwoHints extends RelativeLayout{

    EditText activeField;
    EditText nonActiveEditText;

    final CharSequence hint;
    public TwoHints(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.two_hints_edit_text, this);
        activeField = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.active_edit_text);
        nonActiveEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.non_active_edit_text);
        hint = nonActiveEditText.getHint();
        activeField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                nonActiveEditText.setHint(s.length() !=0 ? "" : hint);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

editetext for xml

```
<you.package.TwoHints
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
```