# How to make the default value of a editText 0 but have it disappear when a user wants to type something int?

Tags: java, android

So basically, if the user doesn't use this edittext, then the default value stays at zero. But if they want to type something in, the zero disappears as soon as they start typing.

I have tried using:

```
android:hint"0"
```

But that doesn't affect the default value.

And when I use:

```
android:text"0"
```

That sets the value of the editText as 0, but you have to manually delete the zero and then start typing in the number that they want to enter.

Comment: Use string value instead of integer value

Comment: I have given same answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/21264550/1979347

Comment: I assume you are making some kind of form? And using that default value when nothing is entered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve that I would do this: Keep the **hint** attribute for ui and maintain the default value programmatically:

```
if(editText.getText().toString().isEmpty())
    //set the value as zero
```

Answer (score 1):

use`android:hint"0"`and do these below in your java code

```
private String editTextValue;
private EditText mEditText;
private static final String DEFAULT_VALUE = "0";

if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditText.getText())){
   editTextValue = DEFAULT_VALUE;
} else {
   editTextValue  = editText.getText();
}
```