# How to disappear the hint in TextInputEditText on receiving focus

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputedittext

I am using a `TextInputEditText` as suggested [here](https://www.journaldev.com/14748/android-textinputlayout-example) to let the user add text up to a specific length.

However, I want that when the `TextInputEditText` view receives focus, the hint should disappear instead of going above the view, as shown in the aforementioned tutorial. In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264359/how-to-make-hint-disappear-when-edittext-is-touched), the solution described is for a `EditText` and it just makes the hint go transparent. However, for a `TextInputEditText`, even if I make the hint transparent on receiving focus, it will still occupy space above the view.

Is there a way to just remove it on receiving focus in the `TextInputEditText`, statically ? It is easy to do it through `OnFocusChangeListener`, but I was looking to do it at compile-time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set focus change listener on EditText and hide hint programmatically when focus is true and show again hint if focus is false and text is empty.

Comment: It is possible to do it dynamically, yes. I wanted to see if it can be done statically at compile time. I will edit the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

try this from the following post 
[how to make hint disappear when edittext is touched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21264359/how-to-make-hint-disappear-when-edittext-is-touched)

```
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus)
            myEditText.setHint("");
        else
            myEditText.setHint("Your hint");
    }
});
```

Comment: It is possible to do it dynamically, yes. I wanted to see if it can be done statically at compile time. I will edit the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want to disappear on focus:

```
textInputEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasfocus) {
            if (hasfocus) {
                textInputLayout.setHint("test");
            } else {
                textInputLayout.setHint(null);
            }
        }
    });
```

Try below code if you want to disappear on typing (in case you are looking for something like this):

```
textInputEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(textInputEditText.getText().toString())) {
                textInputLayout.setHint("test");
            } else {
                textInputLayout.setHint(null);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply add:-

try this from the following post how to make hint disappear when edittext is touched?

```
edittxt.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus)
            edittxt.setHint("");
        else
            edittxt.setHint("hint");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try to set EditText hint in java and it will automatically hide when you click on the EditText.

```
edtPassword.setHint(getString(R.string.YOUR_HINT));
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who have *double hint* in `TextInputLayout`, see [TextInputLayout and EditText double hint issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31251342/textinputlayout-and-edittext-double-hint-issue). We need to set hint to `TextInputLayout`, not `TextInputEditText`.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, hasFocus ->
    inputLayout.hint = if (hasFocus) {
        ""
    } else {
        getString(R.string.some_text)
    }
}
```